# Return Navbar to Original Position After Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set up this page so that when you scroll past the top of the navbar, it becomes sticky and stays at the top of the page.

I want it to return to its original position when you scroll back to the top of the page.

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYyWba) for the work I have right now. How should I change the jQuery so it sticks back in its original position?

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {

    var $header = $("#header"),
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        elementOffset = $header.offset().top,
        distance = (elementOffset - scrollTop);

    if (distance < 0) {
        $header.css({
            "position": "fixed",
            "top": "0px",
            "left": "0",
            "right": "0"
        });
    }
});
```

Right now, this is how I change the header element into a fixed one as the user scrolls down the page.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the solution in another way:

**CSS**

```
.affix {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

**JS**

```
if (distance < 0) {
    $header.addClass("affix");
} else {
    $header.removeClass("affix");
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it works, but when you scroll past the point, none of the styles apply and it renders as straight html. It's as if when I scroll past the point that it removes the original styles and doesn't add a new one and then re-adds it when I scroll back up.

Comment: @apizzimenti maybe you have a conflict with the class name, change `.affix` to something else.

Comment: The application of the class works correctly, but when I'm scrolling after the `.affix` class is applied, it flickers. I looked into the developer tools, and it's constantly switching back and forth between the `.affix` and the default `.header` classes. How can I fix this?

Comment: @apizzimenti I think you have a logic error with the distanceTop, try `if (scrollTop > 50)`